# web data extraction, getting data from tables to CSV

Tags: html, web-scraping, html-table, data-extraction, web-scripting

I want to get data from tables in web pages, which seem to be published using "Excel Publish as Web Page Wizard". I'm aware there are a lot of scraping tools (seem much advanced for such a task) and aware I can write a script, but I'd like to be pointed to something much straightforward, especially that the data is published using an automated tool.

I prefer to have a rails solution.

The data is statistical health data, [here are links to some samples](http://www.cbssyr.org/yearbook/2011/chapter12-AR.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the structure is really simple. On your place I'd just use any language you know and don't spend time for learning third party scrapers. Personally, I use C# for such tasks.

Comment: True, I'm planing to use rails, there's a nice gem called open-uri with a nice blog about using it:
http://www.igvita.com/2007/02/04/ruby-screen-scraper-in-60-seconds/
but I thought such common data structure would have something ready to use.
maybe I should ask in stat.exchange, thanks a lot.